# PHP. Strange numbers in the end of JSON

Tags: php, json

I am reading and saving weather JSON data from forecast.io API. Because I am using free API which has 1000 requests limit per day. So I am requesting API every 10 minutes. I saving update time as timestamp and then I am using this timestamp to check to 10 minutes elapsed or not. However when I am reading JSON file and echoing it, strange number '18706' or '22659' coming out. I do not have idea where it is coming from. How to solve this problem?

Result in browser:

> ....madis-stations":["UTTT"],"units":"si"}}22659

PHP:

```
<?php
    $t = time();
    $last_updated_timestamp = file_get_contents("last_updated_timestamp.txt");

    $delta = ($t - $last_updated_timestamp) / 60;

    if ($delta > 10) {
        $json = file_get_contents('https://api.forecast.io/forecast/MY_API_KEY/41.2667,69.2167?units=si&lang=ru');
        $obj = json_decode($json);
        echo $obj->access_token;

        $fp = fopen('tw.json', 'w');
        fwrite($fp, json_encode($obj));
        fclose($fp);

        $fp2 = fopen('last_updated_timestamp.txt', 'w');
        fwrite($fp2, $t);
        fclose($fp2);

    }

    echo readfile("tw.json");

?>
```

Comment: this gives number i think  echo $obj->access_token;

Comment: `echo $obj->access_token;` ....

Comment: I commented out this line like this: //echo $obj->access_token; Anyways it is giving this number

Comment: still strange number comes?

Comment: @Darren That comes before he echoes the JSON file, not after.

Comment: If you look at the JSON file, is the number in there?

Comment: @Barmar I thought it was potentially that exact thing. What does the `tw.json` file look like Joe?

Comment: @Barmar, tw.json file does not have this number: "madis-stations":["UTTT"],"units":"us"}}

Comment: Why do you decode the JSON and then immediately encode it again? Why not just write `$json` to the file? You can also just `echo $json;`.

Comment: @Barmar, because I am getting values like this: Р§РёСЃС‚Рѕ(here should be Cyrillic text) in JSON file which does not give meaning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
echo readfile("tw.json");
```

to just:

```
readfile("tw.json");
```

`readfile` writes the contents of the file to the output buffer, and then returns the number of bytes that it wrote. You're then echoing that number of bytes.

It seems like you confused `readfile` with `file_get_contents`, which returns the contents of the file as a string.

Comment: I changed echo readfile("tw.json"); TO readfile("tw.json"); Now this is working like magic. Thank you, Barmar!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the echo before readfile. Readfile already prints the content of the file. The return value of readfile is the number of read bytes, which you echoing.

Comment: Isn't that what I answered 10 minutes before you?

Comment: Did it really take you over 10 minutes to write that 2-line answer?

Comment: Yes. First see the question. Take a closer look. What exactly he is doing. And then writing an answer on my mobile without reloading the page

Comment: Sigh, "I'm on mobile" seems to be a common excuse for many poor answers. Sorry to have bothered you.

Comment: Really thought a while about your comment. But yeah maybe you are just right and i have a long way to go and taking a little bit more time to format an answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74793/discussion-between-jens-schulze-and-barmar).